# Java8 group a list of lists to map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Model` and a `Property` class with the following signatures:

```
public class Property {

    public String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Model {

    private List<Property> properties = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Property> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }
}
```

I want a `Map<String, Set<Model>>` from a `List<Model>` where the key would be the name from the `Property` class. How can I can I use java8 streams to group that list by its `Propery`es' name? All `Property`es are unique by name.

It is possible to solve in a single stream or should I split it somehow or go for the classical solution?

Comment: @Holger that is almost irrelevant, it is ok also with a list. I just put there a Set to be sure that I wont have the same `Model` twice, because two models can have the same Property in that list.I think that is not a problem or?

Comment: @Holger I think he means "unique for each model", but there can be multiple models with the same properties.

Comment: @Holger exactly it is as tobias said, sorry for not being accurate.

Comment: Never mind. You may [edit] your question to improve it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
yourModels.stream()
          .flatMap(model -> model.getProperties().stream()
                  .map(property -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(model, property.getName())))
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Entry::getValue, 
                Collectors.mapping(
                    Entry::getKey, 
                    Collectors.toSet())));
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not use `forEach` ?

Here is concise solution using `forEach`

```
Map<String, Set<Model>> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
listOfModels.forEach(currentModel ->
        currentModel.getProperties().forEach(prop -> {
            Set<Model> setOfModels = resultMap.getOrDefault(prop.getName(), new HashSet<>());
            setOfModels.add(currentModel);
            resultMap.put(prop.getName(), setOfModels);
        })
);
```

Comment: I think using `foreach` is indeed simpler here (just wanted to post the same), but instead of `getOrDefault` and then `put`, I'd suggest using `computeIfAbsent`: `resultMap.computeIfAbsent(prop.getName(), s -> new HashSet<>()).add(currentModel))`

Comment: @tobias_k and I wanted to edit for the same thing... :) and yes `computeIfAbsent` is a good suggestion

Comment: Yeah this was my second approach after I couldn't find any "single stream" solution. Indeed it is simpler, and probably more readable than your answer @Eugene but I'll accept yours since that is the most appropriate to the question.

Comment: @Sunflame *readable* is opinion based, I actually read easier the stream approaches... but it's a matter of taste

Comment: @Eugene at most of the cases me too, and I prefer more the stream based solutions, that's why probably I'll use your answer until im not forced to change. For me it is readable, but sadly I'm not the single person who should understand this code, and the prefer less streams :D

Comment: @Eugene well, you can turn the logic of the `forEach` solution into a stream solution: `Map<String, Set<Model>> resultMap = listOfModels.stream().collect(HashMap::new, (map,model) -> model.getProperties().forEach(p -> map.computeIfAbsent(p.getName(),x->new HashSet<>()) .add(model)), (m1,m2)->m2.forEach((k,v) -> m1.merge(k, v, (s1,s2) -> { s1.addAll(s2); return s1; })));`

Comment: I'm curious to know if a  stream solution using reduce operation is possible ? what do you guys reckon ?