# Populating a map's values with values from another list using streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Given that I have a map of type `Map<String, List<Student>>` and a list of type `List<Student>`. how do I populate the map's list values (which are initially empty lists) with elements from `List<Student>` using streams?

The String key is supposed to be a course (like Math or English), and each Student has a set that contains all of their courses. I want to use each course as a key in the map, and its value is a list of all students taking that course.

Here is my code:

```
studentMap.entrySet().stream()
.map(entry -> entry.getValue()).
collect(studentList.stream().map(student -> student.getClasses() //Returns a set of that student's courses));
```

My code does not work as I don't know how to get the set of student's courses from the map's keys of courses.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49317168/java8-group-a-list-of-lists-to-map check here

Comment: So your map has some KVPs initially, and you want to add things to the value of those KVPs. You don't want to create a new map, nor new KVPs. Correct?

Comment: @Sweeper that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If your requirement is to only add to existing `Map` and without creating new KVS you could try something like this :

```
Map<String, List<Student>> map = new HashMap<>();
students.stream()
            .flatMap(student -> student.getClasses().stream().map(classname -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(classname, student)))
            .forEach(entry -> map.get(entry.getKey()).add(entry.getValue())); // use it if you are completly sure that there is a key for this class in your map
```

However it mixes "stream" and "iterative" approach and it modifies a `Map` that is outside of a stream which makes it a side effect.

If you would like to convert your `List` into a new `Map` directly you could use :

```
Map<String, List<Student>> myMap = students.stream()
            .flatMap(student -> student.getClasses().stream().map(classname -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(classname, student)))
            .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, toList())));
```

And then if you are sure that your target map has all keys you could use that to merge :

```
for(Map.Entry<String, List<Student>> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
    map.get(entry.getKey()).addAll(entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: A perfect case for the `flatMapping` collector…

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using nested streams:

```
studentList.stream().forEach(
   student-> {
       student.getCourses().stream().
       forEach(courseName -> {
       List<Student> students = studentMap.get(courseName);
       students.add(student);
       studentMap.put(courseName, students);
       });
     }
   );
```

Comment: You don’t need a Stream when all you do is `forEach`. Further, when you add to a `List` already contained in the `Map`, there is no need to `put` it again. So your code can be simplified to `studentList.forEach(student-> student.getCourses().forEach(courseName -> studentMap.get(courseName).add(student)));`

Answer (score -1):

I am not very familiar yet with streams and collect functions on Java 8 but is it better if you start the stream on List than the studentMap? I wrote a code below using parallel stream and forEach function. Let me know if this is what you are looking for. If you have a more advanced use of Java 8 to achieve your requirement please let me know. I want to improve my knowledge on Java 8 as well.

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

students.add(new Student("a", "Math"));
students.add(new Student("b", "Math"));
students.add(new Student("c", "Science"));
students.add(new Student("d", "Science"));

Map<String, List<Student>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Student>>();

students.parallelStream().forEach(student ->{

    String course = student.course;
        if(map.get(course) != null) {
            map.get(course).add(student);
        }else {
            List<Student> filteredStudent = new ArrayList<Student>();
            filteredStudent.add(student);
            map.put(course, filteredStudent);
        }

    });
```